# SQL query for SQLite / java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date

Tags: java, sqlite

I compiled this, but this code occurs java.sql.SQLException and java.text.ParseException at resultSet.getDate() method.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection
            ("jdbc:sqlite:C:/sqlite-tools/test.db");

            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

            String sql = "CREATE TABLE t1 (" +
                         "no INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                         "date DATE, " +
                         "content TEXT)";
            statement.executeUpdate(sql);

            sql = "INSERT INTO t1 (date, content)" +
                  "VALUES(DATETIME('NOW', 'LOCALTIME'), 'test');";
            statement.executeUpdate(sql);

            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM t1;");
            while(resultSet.next()) {
                // here occurs exception ↓ :(
                Date date = resultSet.getDate("date");
                // here occurs exception ↑ :(
                String text = resultSet.getString("content");

                System.out.println(date + " " + text);
            }

            statement.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

exception explaination is this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Error parsing time stamp
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getDate(JDBC3ResultSet.java:327)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getDate(JDBC3ResultSet.java:346)
at com.planb.main.Main.main(Main.java:35)
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2016-12-20 17:08:07" does not match (\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q \E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q.\E(\p{Nd}++)
at org.sqlite.date.FastDateParser.parse(FastDateParser.java:299)
at org.sqlite.date.FastDateFormat.parse(FastDateFormat.java:490)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getDate(JDBC3ResultSet.java:324)
... 2 more
```

I can't find any solutions for two hours. Help me please. :(

Comment: you get a complete timestamp with time and so on, but you want a date with dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: @조민규, that's not constructive. I was the first who gave the correct answer, but I was downvoted. The guy who based his answer on mine was upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

As @Nurzhan suggested, you have to define date format, and then use it to parse your date as a `String` from `resultSet`. An example:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
while(resultSet.next()) {
    Date date = formatter.parse(resultSet.getString("date"));
    String text = resultSet.getString("content");

    System.out.println(date + " " + text);
}
```

Output will be:

> Tue Dec 20 11:24:40 EET 2016 test

Comment: Thanks a lot. I resolved this error with your code. I couldn't think of getString() method for DATE type.

Comment: That's because `parse` method has `parse(String source)` signature. And you need to pass a string a s a parameter.

Comment: Very nice. The solution is based on my answer, however I've been downvoted several times.

Comment: I referred to your answer. That's pity, I agree, for some reason I was downvoted as well.